# Removing a fixture on body (cocos2d/box2d)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have several balls bouncing around the screen, each with its own body and can bounce off one another. The user can pick up a ball and drag it around the screen.

I'd like to "kill" the selected ball's so that its temporarily removed from the space as long as the user is touching down on it. So other balls will bounce through it as if it weren't there. Upon release, the ball will regain its physical properties and can resume being bounced around.

How should I execute this? Should I remove the body entirely and re-create it upon touchEnded? Any ideas or help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can't add/remove fixtures to an existing body. The way to achieve what you want is to disable the body (set it's active state to false). You could also change it's collision filter/mask so that it won't collide with certain game objects, but still collides with world boundaries for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Box2D body in a custom class that will keep the definition (bodyDef and fixtureDef are reusable) then you can :

- destroy / recreate the fixture at position 0, 0 on the existing body moved by the touch
- OR destroy / recreate the entire body at the touch position

I believe managing fixtures is better for performance.